# How to push forward commit from one GitLab repo to an other private one?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to push commits from one repo to an other in Gatlab with GitLab CI?

Comment: You _could_ push to another repo from your CI jobs. but maybe [repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) (push mirror) would work for your use case?

Comment: can you clarify: pushing all commits to both repos or 1 commit or N arbitrary commits?

Comment: @sytech repository mirroring really takes in place only after 180 minutes? `The update action will time out after 180 minutes. For big repositories, use a clone/push combination.`